# Tomcat7 - creation of jvm failed Windows 10

Tags: jvm, tomcat7

I installed tomcat 7 with Java 11.
When I try to start the tomcat service it crush.
I get an error **the creation of jvm failed**.

Comment: What is your OS and how did you install it ? Also Tomcat 7 is quite old (even if it does not seem to be EOL yet) while Java 11 is quite recent so what you are trying might not be possible.

Comment: OS - Windows 10, I helped someone with this issue, and thought it might help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat 7 is not compatible with Java 11.
I downgraded the Java to 8, now it's working.